# Can you remove recent workbook files from list in c# function

Tags: c#, excel

Is it possible to remove files from deleted files section in microsoft excel,without deleting the file?

I have tried using xlApp.RecentFiles.Maximum. However i feel that i am missing a key functionality here

```
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(folder_name + filename_no_ext,
            default_value, default_value, default_value, 
            default_value, default_value,
            Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
            default_value, true, default_value, 
            default_value, true);
        xlApp.Visible=false;
        xlApp.ScreenUpdating = true;

        Excel.IRecentFile xlRecent;
        xlApp.RecentFiles.Maximum = 2;
```

//          xlRecent.Delete();

```
        xlWorkBook.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();
```

i would like for the code to remove the files from recent files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution was to set the variable called mru to false, when saving the file, the code above was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.recentfile.delete?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_RecentFile_Delete) shows a `RecentFile.Delete` method which states it "Deletes the object." Therefore you should just be able to:

```
foreach(var rf in xlApp.RecentFiles)
{
    rf.Delete();
}
```

Comment: Delete is not a method on rf

Comment: @TomEdwards the documentation states otherwise.

Comment: .RecentFile has a delete method but .RecentFile**s** does not.

Comment: @TomEdwards correct. RecentFiles is a collection of RecentFile. Hence the foreach over it.

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Delete' and no extension method 'Delete' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: @TomEdwards will the object cast to a RecentFile? e.g. ((RecentFile)rf).Delete();

Comment: I have been able to get this to work, thank you for your help so far and will mark you answer as correct, had issues with the type of rf...is there anyway to only delete the most recent recent files?

Comment: You can delete specific ones by finding them in the collection and just deleting those rather than every single one in the foreach. There's no timestamp property so you'd have to find another way to find the specific files or verify that the last items in the collection are the most recent. Assuming they are you could use RecentFiles.Last() for example to get the last element and delete that.

Comment: how do i find them in the collection?
and .last() didn't work